# labelprovider getImage not called on ListViewer

Tags: swt, jface

I have a ListViewer with a custom LabelProvider.
The getText part works fine, but the getImage method of the LabelProvider never gets called.

I also tried to use a DecoratedLabelProvider but this did not work either.

```
class RadioLabelProvider extends LabelProvider{

    Display d;
    public RadioLabelProvider(Display d)
    {
        this.d = d;
    }

    @Override
    public Image getImage(Object element)
    {
        Image image = d.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_INFORMATION);
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText(Object element)
    {
        RadioElement re = (RadioElement) element;
        return re.getIP();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
availableDevicesList = new ListViewer(this, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
availableDevicesList.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
availableDevicesList.setLabelProvider(new RadioLabelProvider(getDisplay()));
availableDevicesList.setInput(devices);
```

What am I doing wrong? Or does the ListViewer not support images?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that on ListViewers getImage really wont get called.

Instead I used a TableViewer with a single column. Also the DecoratingLableProvider works so I can set the image depening on the objects status.

Answer (score 3):

In the JFace source header comment of class `ListViewer` you find that a ListViewer is

> A concrete viewer based on an SWT `List` control.

and

> Note that the SWT `List` control only supports the display of strings, **not** icons. If you need to show icons for items, use `TableViewer` instead.